# Why should question contain incorrect source be downvoted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

[Why can "core" be a plural form of "core"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/165982/11458)

This question receives 3 downvotes. One of the downvoter says that because it contains incorrect source. But even so, then why doesn't it show any research effort, not useful or unclear?

Answer (score 2):

The reason's already in the comments, [straight from the horse's mouth](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/from+the+horse%27s+mouth). It's [because the question relies entirely on a lousy source when there are much better ones out there](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/165982/why-can-core-be-a-plural-form-of-core#comment331609_165982).

That's a two-for-one deal, since that shows a certain lack of research effort in the question (any surprising assertions should usually be checked against other sources; dictionaries should be preferred for anything they can be used for, such as plural forms), as well as a lack of usefulness (since while it's possible some other users may run across the same article and be similarly confused, it's far less likely than most other types of confusions, which could arise from ordinary usage in any source).

Comment: but I have added after the first downvote that other reliable sources don't help, so this should prove the research effort point at least?